# ¿Cómo hago un update a un registro, despues de cierto tiempo usando Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Lo que intento hacer es que si cambie un estado de mi registro en la base de datos, después de cierto tiempo (de 4 horas a 6 meses) se cambie automáticamente a otro estado. He leído que quizás con Celery, pero no se si realmente aplica a mi problema.

También he leido sonbre `django-cron-jobs` pero no se si sea posible pasarle como argumento 6 meses. La idea es que el update no dependa de el sistema operativo, sino que se pueda lanzar el update desde Django.

Comment: Hola, ¿que has intentado?

Comment: Hola, Aun no intento nada, me gustaría saber cual de las opciones que he mirado parece mas acorde a mi problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, si quieres hacerlo con Django entonces tendrías que usar un comando de gestión personalizado (los que se usan con `manage.py`).

---

### Hello World Command

Para crear un comando necesitas crear el script en una ruta que tiene que tener las siguiente forma:

```
[nombre_app]/management/commands/[nombre_comando].py
```

Por lo tanto, a nivel de estructura tienes que crear lo siguiente:

```
├── [nombre_app]
│   └── management
│       ├── __init__.py  
│       └── commands  
│           ├── __init__.py  
│           └── [nombre_comando].py
```

Considerando una aplicación dentro de tu proyecto llamada `test` y el comando llamado `hola.py`, este es un comando en su forma más básica:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Comando que saluda'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write('¡Hola!')
```

Para usarlo:

```
$ python manage.py hola --help
usage: manage.py hola [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS]
                      [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback] [--no-color]

Comando que saluda

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  (más...)

$ python manage.py hola
¡Hola!
```

### Comando Específico

No sé exactamente el contexto bajo el cual estás trabajando ya que no has dado mayor detalle al respecto, sin embargo, se me ocurre que podrías usa una notación como esta:

```
4h -> 4 horas
2d -> 2 días
3m -> 3 meses
```

Si tienes alguna mejor idea también la puedes implementar, tampoco sé de qué depende o cúales son los estados que deberían ser considerados por lo que la tarea de parsear, y actualizar con el estado correcto, es tuya. Considera este ejemplo (`actualizar.py`) como el esqueleto de tu comando:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Cambiar el estado de los registros de acuerdo al tiempo especificado'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        # Argumento posicional
        parser.add_argument('tiempo', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        tiempo = options.get('tiempo', '').lower() # Para casos con 4h o 4H
        if tiempo.endswith('h'):
            hours = tiempo.split('h')[0]
            # Tu lógica
        elif tiempo.endswith('d'):
            days = tiempo.split('d')[0]
            # Tu lógica
        elif tiempo.endswith('m'):
            months = tiempo.split('m')[0]
            # Tu lógica
        else:
            # No debería llegar hasta aquí, muestra un mensaje de error
        self.stdout.write('¡Registros actualizados!')
```

Usos de ejemplo:

```
$ python manage.py actualizar 8h

$ python manage.py actualizar 20d

$ python manage.py actualizar 5m
```

Habría que validar, si es necesario, algunas cosas más, como casos en los que se pasan valores como `4HD` o `9HH` aunque tampoco es bueno ser tan paranoico con el tema a menos que estés pensando en sabotear tu propia sistema.