# ¿Cómo actualizar el estado del registro por el valor de la hora de Inicio/Fin en sus campos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Dado el siguiente modelo

```
STATUS = [(0, "Pendiente"), (1, "Iniciado"), (2, "Finalizado")]
class Tarea(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
```

Cuando el usuario da de alta un nuevo registro, las fechas `start_time` y `end_time` están en blanco.

Estoy buscando la forma de automatizar lo siguiente:

**Cuando el usuario ingresa las fechas de `start_time` y `end_time` (por ejemplo, desde un una vista `DetailView`, presiona un botón para programar el inicio y final de la tarea en un formulario)**

1. **Actualizar el campo `status=1` cuando la hora del servidor coincida con la hora en `start_time`**
2. **Actualizar el campo `status=2` cuando la hora del servidor coincida con la hora en `end_time`**

No estoy seguro de que con que o que puedo utilizar para esto, si lo hago desde el `model.py` o desde el `view.py`

Lo mas parecido que esta publicado esta en aquí

[¿Cómo hago un update a un registro, despues de cierto tiempo usando Django?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10371/c%C3%B3mo-hago-un-update-a-un-registro-despues-de-cierto-tiempo-usando-django)

aunque la actualización en este caso, depende del administrador y no del usuario final, no estoy viendo que se aplique en mi caso.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar señales, específicamente la señal [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#post-save):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.utils import timezone
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender = Tarea)
def set_status(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        if timezone.now() == instance.start_time: 
            instance.status = 1
        elif timezone.now() == instance.end_time:
            instance.status = 2
```

Dicha señal, se encarga de hacer las validaciones que mencionaste, después de que se guarde cada objeto del modelo `Tarea`, tambien cabe recalcar que dichas validaciones se hacen **solo cuando se crea el objeto, no cuando se actualiza**, si quieres que las validaciones se hagan cuando el objeto se actualiza, simplemente elimina el `if kwargs['created']:`.

Si no sabes como funcionan las señales, visita la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch). Un resumen simple de que son:

> Las señales de Django son una forma de informar a su aplicación de
> ciertas tareas (como un modelo antes o después de guardar o eliminar)
> cuando se lleva a cabo. Estas señales le permiten realizar acciones de
> su elección inmediatamente después de que se libera la señal.

Por otra parte, si no tienes el soporte de zona horaria habilitado ([`settings.USE_TZ`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ)), no es necesario usar `timezone.now()`, puedes usar `datetime.datetime.now()`, si lo tienes habilitado lo mejor es usar `timezone.now()`.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Creo que no es valido para mi problema, debido a que la condición  `if timezone.now() == instance.start_time` solo se evalúa en el instante actual en que se actualiza, en otras palabras, si al momento de actualizar, `start_time = 14:53:42` y el valor de `timezone.now() = 14:50:42` nunca cambiaria el estado.

Answer (score 1):

**Hasta ahora esta es la solución encontrada**

Utilizando el paquete [***Django Q***](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) de la siguiente forma

1. [Instalar](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) y [configurar](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configure.html)
   en mi caso, en `settings.py` registro el paquete

   INSTALLED_APPS = [
   # Otras apps registradas
   'django_q',
   ]

y añado la síguete línea

```
Q_CLUSTER = {
    # nombre de la carpeta donde esta el archivo settings.py
    "name": "conf",
    # Usa ORM de Django y la base de datos default
    "orm": "default",
}
```

finalmente, aplicar la migración, de manera que también se podrá acceder desde la ruta `/admin/django_q/`

```
    python manage.py migrate
```

2. Crear un archivo `tasks.py`, preferentemente, dentro de la carpeta de la aplicación que maneje el modelo en cuestión, en mi caso la app se llama `core` y es la que define el modelo `Tarea`

   ```
   from .models import Tarea

   def set_status(id, status):
       tarea = Tarea.objects.get(id=id)
       tarea.status = status
       tarea.save()
   ```
3. Iniciar el proceso **Django-Q** desde una terminal diferente en la que este corriendo el servidor local del proyecto (una terminar distinta de donde ejecutan el comando `python manage.py runserver`). Si están usando entornos virtuales, deben activar el entorno y obviamente, debería ser el mismo entorno donde esta instalado `django` y `django-q`

   ```
   python manage.py qcluster
   ```
4. Escribir la vista que permite actualizar el la tarea con las fechas de inicio-fin.

En mi caso, siguiendo el requerimiento del problema, tengo una vista `UpdateView`, sobre escribo el método `post` de la siguiente manera

```
from django_q.models import Schedule

class ProgramarTarea(UpdateView):
    # . . .
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        # Si las horas ingresadas son validas (hora de inicio menor a la hora de fin, etc.)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Se obtiene la instancia del objeto actualizado (la tarea que se acaba de actualizar)
            obj = form.save()
            # _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
            # Se crea instancias del modelo Schedule
            # Esta instancia es para poner la tarea con status=1
            Schedule.objects.create(
                name=f'{obj.id}',
                # Esta es la ruta de la función definida en tasks.py
                func='core.tasks.set_status',
                hook='hooks.print_result',
                # Los argumentos de la función set_status(id, status)
                args=f'{obj.id},{1}',
                # 'O' significa que solo se ejecuta una vez
                schedule_type='O',
                # get_start_datetime() retorna un tipo datetime
                # Es un método escrito en el modelo Tarea
                # debido a que los campos son models.TimeField
                # y hace falta añadir la fecha del día actual
                next_run=obj.get_start_datetime()
            )
            # Esta instancia es para poner la tarea con status=2
            Schedule.objects.create(
                name=f'{obj.id}',
                func='core.tasks.set_status',
                hook='hooks.print_result',
                args=f'{obj.id},{2}',
                schedule_type='O',
                next_run=obj.get_end_datetime()
            )
            # _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
            # Lo que sigue es propio de la vista UpdateView
            return redirect('core:tarea-detail', pk=obj.id)
        self.object = None
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Y bueno, para ir concluyendo, lo que entiendo es que que mientras se esta ejecutando el proceso **Django-Q** (paso 3), este se encarga de consultar periodicamente las tablas de las distintas `tasks`, en nuestro caso, la tabla para el modelo `Schedule` tendrá registrada la `tasks` creada en el paso 4.

La fuente principal de donde he sacado la idea es la siguiente:
[Simple scheduled tasks with Django Q](https://mattsegal.dev/simple-scheduled-tasks.html)

Espero que pueda servirles

**Saludos**